Отрисовка элемента объекта QwtPlot поверх других элементов (библиотека QWT)
Помогите пожалуйста. Необходимо отрисовать элемент QwtPlotMarker поверх QwtCurvePlot, для повышения производительности отрисовки (дабы обойти метод replot(), который перестраивает всё содержимое QwtPlot).
Пытаюсь создать свой класс QwtWidgetOverlay по аналогии с примером из QWT itemeditor, но не понимаю с чего стоило бы начать
Прикрепляю ссылку на пример itemeditor
https://github.com/opencor/qwt/tree/master/examples/itemeditor
